# Bigquery: grant permissions on specific tables by Common Expression Language (CEL) conditions

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

`roles/bigquery.user` is the permission to use some BigQuery datasets. But we need to grant permissions of a specific tables instead of the whole dataset. How to do it by [CEL](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) and condition builder?

Thanks

Comment: Does solution described in [Controlling access to tables and views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls#bq) is what you are looking for? There is also an option to use [Authorized Views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views)?

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comment section you should check GCP Documentation [Controlling access to tables and views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls)

> This document describes how to use BigQuery Table ACL to control access to tables and views. For an overview of BigQuery Table ACL, see [Introduction to table access controls.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-access-controls-intro)

After you create a table or view, you can set its policy in the following ways:

- using the Cloud Console
- using the `bq set-iam-policy` command
- calling the `tables.setIamPolicy` method
- using the `GRANT` or `REVOKE` data control language statements

As addition, you could also check [Authorized views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorized-views)